# No view found for id in a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have created an activity that I am using for barcode scanning. The `onCreate` looks like this:

```
public class GradeScreenScanner extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    public static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;

    protected ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    protected FirebaseFirestore db;
    protected String scanResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(scannerView);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Once I have a result I am then wanting to launch a new fragment like so:

```
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

ScreenFragment screenFragment = new ScreenFragment();

screenFragment.db = db;
screenFragment.serialNumberScanned = serialNumberScanned;

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack("screen")
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, screenFragment)
        .commit();
```

But I get the following error that I am not sure how to deal with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08005a (uk.wefix:id/content_frame) for fragment ScreenFragment{6262536 #1 id=0x7f08005a}
```

Just in case, the fragments onCreate looks like this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grade_screens_layout, container, false);

    return myView;
}
```

Help appreciated.

```
@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(view);
}
```

Comment: can you check if your activity layout contains a view with this id R.id.content_frame ?

Comment: Where is `setContentView()` in your `GradeScreenScanner` activity

Comment: cant you post the xml of : grade_screens_layout ?

Comment: It's missing something, there isn't a content_frame in the activities xml. My bad!

Comment: @LewisSmith it's missing your view :)  you are not assigning any view to your fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>
```

Was missing from the xml in the activity view. My error, well spotted [Umair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3548046/umair)

Answer (score 0):

yes , usually when you get No view found for id or nullPointer i suggest you to check:
1-`android:id="@+id/`
2- `findViewById`
3- in the java class the variable declaration
in most cases it works ;) 
good luck.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please remember that your answers need to be detailed and provide code examples to make sure it's clear. Like mine below.